# ActiveRecord - has_many :through, :dependent => :destroy sql is not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

I am trying to "counter cache" the number of posts in each tag. The after save callback is working but the after destroy is not. Looks like destroy sql is not correct.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_tags, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :post_tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_tags, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :posts, :through => :post_tags
end

class PostTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name =  :posts_tags
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag

  after_save :update_tag_posts_count
  after_destroy :update_tag_posts_count

  def update_tag_posts_count
    tag.posts_count = tag.posts.count
    tag.save
  end
end
```

The test fails

```
# @tag.posts_count == 10
Failure/Error: @tag.posts.first.destroy 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
 Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'posts_tags.' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM `posts_tags` WHERE `posts_tags`.`` = NULL
```

The correct sql should be

```
DELETE FROM `posts_tags` WHERE `posts_tags`.`post_id` = {the post id}
```

Comment: Try using set_table_name instead of table_name= ? I think that the method set_table_name changes a few more things.

Comment: @joe Pym That didn't work. Besides, set_table_name is now deprecated. -> DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling set_table_name is deprecated. Please use `self.table_name = 'the_name'` instead.

Comment: I am getting a very similar error in my situation. I too would like an answer.

Comment: I have the same issue, I think it's because my Tag table has no `id` primary key. It's a table of `post_id:integer`, `name:string`

Comment: @user1149547 can you add your destroy method here

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue, the fix for me was to add a primary key column to the join table (PostTag in your case).

It seems that rails needs a primary key for the `:dependent => :destroy` option to work.

Comment: Thanks, don't know about OP but this worked for me. For `:dependent => :destroy` Rails doesn't run `WHERE foreign_key=smth` as one would expect, it fetches children and then runs `WHERE id=smth` for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest separate increment/decrement functions and not using count + save. This should function properly, perform well, not trigger side-effects on Tag, and not mess up your count in race conditions.

```
class PostTag < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag

  after_create  :increment_tag_posts_counter
  after_destroy :decrement_tag_posts_counter

  private

  def increment_tag_posts_counter
    Tag.increment_counter :posts_count, post_id
  end

  def decrement_tag_posts_counter
    Tag.decrement_counter :posts_count, post_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

May be because in models you used

```
#post.rb
has_many :post_tags, :dependent => :destroy
#tag.rb
has_many :post_tags, :dependent => :destroy
```

instead of

```
#post.rb
has_many :posts_tags, :dependent => :destroy
#tag.rb
has_many :posts_tags, :dependent => :destroy
```

?